# что за ошибка в laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, composer

пытаюсь выполнить любую команду через ssh, например `php artisan route:list` и выдает такую ошибку

```
In ArgvInput.php line 281:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по информации с laracasts проблема с php настройкой `register_argc_argv`.

Необходимо в `php.ini` включить `register_argc_argv`.

Решение взял [отсюда](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-artisan-schedule-run-getting-invalid-foreach) и [отсюда](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-when-scheduling-task).